# Problem using Buttons to swich LED's on and off

Tags: gpio, python, rpi.gpio, led, raspbian-wheezy

Im making a prototype of a model lift shaft. The LEDs in this example will eventually be replaced with relays.
 *Side Note* For those who do not know, a limit switch is a microswitch plces at the top,bottom of the lift shaft that the lift car will activate when it reaces the set height.
so here is my code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(7,False)# Button Limit switch
GPIO.setup(11,False)#button - Call (ground)
GPIO.setup(12,False)#button- Up (Ground floor)
GPIO.setup(13,GPIO.OUT)#LED
GPIO.setup(15,GPIO.OUT)#LED
GPIO.setup(16,False)#button - Down (1st floor)
GPIO.setup(18,False)#button - Call (1st floor)
GPIO.setup(19,False)#button - Limit switch
GPIO.output(13, False)
GPIO.output(15, False)

def down():
    if GPIO.input(7) == False:
        GPIO.output(13,True)
        print ("Going Down")
        while GPIO.output(13, True):
            if GPIO.input(7) == True:
                GPIO.output(13, False)
                Print ("You have Reached The Ground Floor")
                button_select()
            else:
                pass
    else:
        pass

def button_select():
    if GPIO.input(11) == True:
        Print ("Called to Ground Floor")
        down()
    elif GPIO.input(16) == True:
        Print ("Down To Ground Floor selected")
        down()
    else:
        pass
```

the problem I have is that when I press the limit switch on the ground floor, the LED stays lit, rather than turning off. If this were a real lift system, I'm sure you could see why this is a problem!
I'm using sudo idle on raspian wheezy.
Any help to sole this would be greatly appreciated.  I'll keep you informed if I find a solution.

Comment: Could you edit your code and correct the GPIO.setup(11,False) entries, several examples.  It's impossible to tell if they are meant to be inputs or outputs.

Comment: What is wrong with the GIPO.setup(11, False) entries?

Comment: How do we know what they are doing?  I know you should be setting some GPIO as inputs and some GPIO as outputs.  Why aren't you using GPIO.IN and GPIO.OUT?

Comment: It is just the way I've always been tought. I don't suppose it would interfere with the code, would it?

Comment: No, it just inteferferes with the ability of others to work out what the code is intended to do.

Comment: Well, we obviously have different styles if coding.

Comment: This is not a question of style.  What you are doing is plain wrong.  If you have been taught this then ask for your money back.  The function expects one of two constants, GPIO.IN or GPIO.OUT.  Not 0, 1, 2 etc. Not True, False.  By using the wrong constants your code could be broken at any new release of RPi.GPIO.

Comment: It was a reliable electrician on instructables that taught me this style of coding, if you would like to introduce me to a GPIO.IN/OUT based tutorial website, I'd sure be happy to give it a go! The numbers are which number pin it is referring to, and True/False equates to 1/0. It seems verry logical to me. I am, however, wandering where you found the numbers 0, 1, or 2 in the code!

Comment: Sam, it might be worth considering that you are *asking other people for help* -- and likely have now alienated a potential source.  I don't use python, but I agree with joan that GPIOs are set according to function and part of the purpose of using named values is in order to write clear code.  Otherwise you are at best using [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Unnamed_numerical_constants), a practice which has been considered **poor style in any context** for a very long time.  Doing something the wrong way is a not a matter of taste.  But good luck...

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Do you know of any online tutorial sites to help me learn? I still don't understand where Joan saw the numbers 0, 1, or 2.

Comment: The numbers are the pin numbers, I don't see how they're "Magic"

Comment: @SamMason The 'magic numbers' relates to using `True` and `False` to represent `GPIO.IN` and `GPIO.OUT` respectively. This only works because in Python `True == 1` and `False == 0` and `GPIO.OUT == 1` and `GPIO.IN == 0`. In a line like `GPIO.setup(11, False)` or `GPIO.setup(11, 0)` the `False` or `0` is a 'magic number' because it's not clear what it means (its meaning is non-numeric, unlike the `11`). Using `GPIO.OUT` and `GPIO.IN` is self documenting.

Comment: Documentation for this is here https://pythonhosted.org/RPIO/rpio_py.html#gpio-input-output it may just be that the tutorial you watched was based on an older version?

Comment: Ah great thanks. I understand now. I've changed it and it still doesn't work, but I'm working in it.

Comment: @SamMason if you can post your updated code I'll have a crack at figuring out the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I reworked your code to be a little tidier, but then realised that the `RPIO` module actually provides an event-handler like interface which is much preferable to waiting in loops. In fact, this may be the source of your original bug.  So I've reworked your example to use interrupts to handle the events (button presses, limit switches) that are present in your system.

Here it is in parts. First, further to the comment about 'magic numbers', here we make them even less magic by defining some constants that we can use throughout the code. This allows us to refer to buttons by *what they do*:

```
import RPIO
RPIO.setmode(RPIO.BOARD)

# Define constants for clarity
LIMIT_SWITCH_DOWN = 7
BUTTON_CALL_GROUND = 11
BUTTON_UP_GROUND = 12

LED_MOVING_DOWN = 13
LED_MOVING_UP = 15

BUTTON_DOWN_1ST = 16
BUTTON_CALL_1ST = 18
LIMIT_SWITCH_UP = 19
```

Next follows the equivalent to your own setup, but now using these and the RPIO constants. Hopefully you can see how this is clearer:

```
RPIO.setup(LIMIT_SWITCH_DOWN, RPIO.IN)
RPIO.setup(BUTTON_CALL_GROUND, RPIO.IN)
RPIO.setup(BUTTON_UP_GROUND, RPIO.IN)

RPIO.setup(LED_MOVING_DOWN, RPIO.OUT)
RPIO.setup(LED_MOVING_UP, RPIO.OUT)

RPIO.setup(BUTTON_DOWN_1ST, RPIO.IN)
RPIO.setup(BUTTON_CALL_1ST, RPIO.IN)
RPIO.setup(LIMIT_SWITCH_UP, RPIO.IN)

# Initialisation
RPIO.output(LED_MOVING_DOWN, False)
RPIO.output(LED_MOVING_UP, False)
```

Next, we need to define our *event handler* functions. These are the functions that will be called when an event occurs. See the documentation on [RPIO interrupts](https://pythonhosted.org/RPIO/rpio_py.html#gpio-interrupts):

```
def limit_switch_down(gpio_id, val):
    if val == True: # We've hit the limit switch
        # Turn off the light (?! and stop the motor!)
        RPIO.output(LED_MOVING_DOWN, False)
        print("You have reached the first floor")

def limit_switch_up(gpio_id, val):
    if val == True: # We've hit the limit switch
        # Turn off the light (?! and stop the motor!)
        RPIO.output(LED_MOVING_UP, False)
        print("You have reached the first floor")
```

Taking these first two as an example, when the button `LIMIT_SWITCH_DOWN` is pressed, the top function is hit. Note that because the `gpio_id` is passed, you could combine this into a single function:

```
def limit_switch(gpio_id, val):
    if val == True:
        if gpio_id == LIMIT_SWITCH_DOWN:
            # Turn off the light (?! and stop the motor!)
            RPIO.output(LED_MOVING_DOWN, False)
            print("You have reached the first floor")

        elif gpio_id == LIMIT_SWITCH_UP:
            # Turn off the light (?! and stop the motor!)
            RPIO.output(LED_MOVING_UP, False)
            print("You have reached the first floor")
```

The rest of the functions follow the same pattern:

```
def button_call_ground(gpio_id, val):
    # Turn on the down light
    RPIO.output(LED_MOVING_DOWN, True)
    print("Going down!")

def button_call_1st(gpio_id, val):
    # Turn on the down light
    RPIO.output(LED_MOVING_UP, True)
    print("Going up!")

def button_up_ground(gpio_id, val):
    # Turn on the down light
    RPIO.output(LED_MOVING_UP, True)
    print("Going up!")

def button_down_1st(gpio_id, val):
    # Turn on the down light
    RPIO.output(LED_MOVING_DOWN, True)
    print("Going down!")
```

Now the callback functions are defined, we can attach these functions to the interrupts as follows. Again using constants and labels makes this very clear:

```
# RPIO interrupt callbacks; when buttons are pressed (or limits triggered)
# the respective function will called
RPIO.add_interrupt_callback(LIMIT_SWITCH_DOWN, limit_switch_down)
RPIO.add_interrupt_callback(BUTTON_CALL_GROUND, button_call_ground)
RPIO.add_interrupt_callback(BUTTON_UP_GROUND, button_up_ground)

RPIO.add_interrupt_callback(BUTTON_DOWN_1ST, button_down_1st)
RPIO.add_interrupt_callback(BUTTON_CALL_1ST, button_call_1st)
RPIO.add_interrupt_callback(LIMIT_SWITCH_UP, limit_switch_up)
```

The last step is to start the event loop. This will 'sit' in a loop, waiting for events from the defined interrupts (buttons/switches) and call the relevant functions when those states are found:

```
# Start the event loop
RPIO.wait_for_interrupts()
```

Note that the above code doesn't apply any sense checks, or use state. So for example, you can call the lift up when it's at the first floor. Have a think about how you would implement that.

A general style hint about your own code: Don't call back into the calling function (i.e. calling `button_select()` from inside `down()` which was itself called from `button_select()`). This is uncontrolled recursion and will eventually crash - if your code runs long enough. Instead, structure your code to have a 'main loop' and 'fall' back out of your subroutines into that.

Comment: @goldilocks Not used GPIO before today so wasn't aware of the interrupt-callback handling. Updated the post with what I hope is 'best practise'.

Comment: Much appreciated!

Comment: hi, great advice, the code looks great. I wrote it into my pi (after attatching the pins to the appropriate breadboard pins), but I get the error message _NameError: name 'RPIO' is not defined_

Comment: @SamMason apologies, that was a typo — it should read `GPIO` on those lines

Comment: _AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'add_interrupt_callback'_ any idea why this error now pops up?

Comment: My mistake, the GPIO was the typo. This code uses the RPIO module (which is a drop-in replacement for GPIO but with event handlers). https://pythonhosted.org/RPIO/rpio_py.html   ...not near my Pi at the moment to test unfortunately.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without the rpio module? I've been having trouble installing it, as I am finding it hard to connect to the internet recently.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without the rpio module? I've been having trouble installing it, as I am finding it hard to connect to the internet recently.

Comment: @SamMason Yes there is. I posted an approach originally but edited it. Here is a gist: https://gist.github.com/mfitzp/59a579e65d029129ad78 - this only alters the down function but hopefully that will solve the issue.